# running a.out on another computer

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

I've successfully compiled a program (including SDL) on my computer (Ubuntu 12) and the `a.out` runs just fine!

Now, if I send the `a.out` to a friend, it just does not work. (gives simple error message (`"Can't be run.."`) or something)
But if I compile the corresponding source-file on my friends computer again, it works!

How do I have to pack/compile/make my program to make it runnable on other computer?

Comment: He probably doesn't have compatible versions of the libraries - SDL, glibc, maybe even libstdc++. What versions do you have and what versions does he have? You may be able to get away statically linking your binary, otherwise you'll have to compile for the minimum library version that you'd like to support.

Comment: Might need to do a chmod on the exe but the answer below applies and is the way forward i would suggest

Comment: That's a good question. In forty years, nobody has come up with a simple answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executable are often specific to the environment/machine they were created on. Even if the same processor/hardware is involved, there may be dependencies on libraries that may prevent executables from just running on other machines.

Can you just send the source code with instructions to compile? Assuming there is no NDA or other issues preventing that approach (I only suggest that since you mentioned this worked for you)

Of course, in the end *it is* possible, after all that's how binaries are distributed, but they will be carefully constructed and will have statically linked libraries (ie everything is part of the executable).

Comment: I haven't the source here now, but this snippet here should have the same effect: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/linux/cli/index.php

Comment: I think SDL is the problem.. dunno

Comment: @user1511417 probably, I'm not familiar with it unfortunately. But this is not an uncommon problem/dilemma (distributing software) that you have experienced.

Comment: And how do I link SDL for example with my executable?

Comment: @user1511417 As mentioned, unfortunately I am not familiar with SDL. I think that is actually a different question from the general one you posted (though of course related :) - I would post a new and different question to get an answer to that specific follow-up question.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your friend to do the following:

```
 chmod +x a.out
 ldd a.out
```

What does he see?  I assume, of course, that the two environments are largely similar (e.g., both run Ubuntu, etc.)

Comment: I seriously think, this is what he needs. Besides, distributing binary when source is available is something you should avoid if you can.(I guess no NDA is involved here).